# Linking Slicers Together (Different Data Sets)

Tags: excel, vba

I have three separate data sets for which I am trying to connect slicers together for.

I currently have Excel 2010.

I'm looking for a way to use VBA to connect a master table pivot's slicer to specific slave pivots slicers which are from a different data source.

Comment: These were the initial search results I found. Have you tried any of these? Or searching SO for similar search terms ?  https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=slicers+different+data+sources&oq=slicers+with+different+&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0.6782j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Yes ... I have looked online for a few days now ... nothing seems to work much.

Comment: Hello @EeshaP, please check out [ask] a question with an [mcve]. Show us what you have tried/got so far and what part isn't working. A [random](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?55508-How-to-use-VBA-Slicer-to-connect-two-PivotTable) search to get you started.